# how to just access the count of products through another model which are connected by foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    




class Product(models.Model):
    category        = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name    = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug            = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

Here what i want is just the number of the product present in each category just the number of product i know i have can fire somequery

```
cat = Category.objects.all()
```

run loop for cat

```
prod_cat = Product.object.filter(category=cat)
```

But i belive its not the efficient way to achive this

Answer (score 1):

By using `annotate` like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Count

>>> categories = Category.objects.annotate(Count('product'))

>>> categories[0].product__count
```

Answer (score 0):

Full examples and understanding here:
https://able.bio/dfernsby/django-queryset-annotations-with-conditions--19d4cb4b

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).